# Update ComboBox ItemsSource based on SelectedItem of another ComboBox inside a Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, datagrid, combobox, selecteditem

I've 2 `ComboBoxes` inside a `DataGrid`. I want to update 2nd `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` when a selection is made in the 1st `ComboBox`. I just started to learn `Silverlight` and I'm trying to follow `MVVM` pattern. So heres what I've got so far.

**Model**

```
public class Country : ViewModelBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name {...}
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
public class City : ViewModelBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name {...}        
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
public class Location : ViewModelBase
{
    private City city;
    public City City {...}

    private Country country;
    public Country Country {...}
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class CountryCityViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Location selectedLocation;
    public Location SelectedLocation {...}

    IRepo Repo { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities { get; set; }       

    public CountryCityViewModel(IRepo repo)
    {
        this.Repo = repo;

        Countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>(repo.LoadCountries());
        Cities = new ObservableCollection<City>();
        Locations = new ObservableCollection<Location>(repo.LoadLocations());

        this.PropertyChanged += CountryCityViewModel_PropertyChanged;

    }

    private void UpdateCityComboBoxItemsSource(object obj)
    {
        Country selCountry = ( (Country) obj );
        if (obj != null)
        {
            UpdateCities(selCountry);
        }
    }

    void CountryCityViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, 
                       System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedLocation")
        {
            UpdateCities(SelectedLocation.Country);
        }
    }
    private void UpdateCities(Country country)
    {
        var newCities = Repo.LoadCities(country);
        Cities.Clear();
        foreach (var city in newCities)
        {
            Cities.Add(city);
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("Cities");
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Custom:CustomDataGrid x:Name="CountryCity" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                       ColumnWidth="*" RowHeight="25"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Locations}" 
                       SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedLocation, 
                       Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Custom:CustomDataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Country.Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="CountryComboBox" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                  AncestorType=Custom:CustomDataGrid}, 
                                  Path=DataContext.Countries}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Country, 
                                  Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                           <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                             <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                               <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                  AncestorType=Custom:CustomDataGrid},                                                                                               
                                  Path=
                                  DataContext.                                 
                                   CountryComboBoxItemSelectedCommand}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="City">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=City.Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CityyComboBox" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                       AncestorType=Custom:CustomDataGrid}, 
                       Path=DataContext.Cities}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding Path=City, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                       DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </Custom:CustomDataGrid.Columns>
</Custom:CustomDataGrid>
```

First I tried to catch `PropertyChanged` event of `SelectedLocation`. But this only helps in updating `Cities` when I select next row of the datagrid. This is not the desired functionality. I want to update `Cities` as soon as a selection is made in the `CountryComboBox`.

I tried to experiment with `EventTriggers` but I'm not sure which event and of which control I should listen to inorder to get the `Selecteditem` of `CountryComboBox`.

Any suggestions or links is greatly  appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Using `CommandParameter` property of the `EventTrigger` inside `CountryComboBox` seems to do the trick for me.

```
public ICommand CountryComboBoxItemSelectedCommand { get; set; }
CountryComboBoxItemSelectedCommand = new 
                                  RelayCommand(UpdateCityComboBoxItemsSource);
```

and xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CountryComboBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Countries,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Custom:CustomDataGrid}}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Country, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding
          Path=DataContext.CountryComboBoxItemSelectedCommand,
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Custom:CustomDataGrid}}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=CountryComboBox}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: How is the ItemsSource supposed to change? Change it to what? I can only see one list of city codes in your code, so what do you want to accomplish? Exchange that list to the exact same list again? Or do you want to change the city code inside the Address object to match the city name?

Comment: @Martin my question probably didn't had the best of examples. I've updated question with a better one. What I was looking for is when a user selects a `Country` from the `CountryComboBox`, I want to update the options available for the `CityComboBox`with a collection of `City` objects related to the selected `Country`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this so many times.

What I used to do is Create a SelectedItem property for Country combo box in XAML.

Suppose, name of SelectedItem property is "SelectedCountry". Now go to Setter of this property and assign a Itemsource to city combobox in MVVM.

```
private Country _SelectedCountry;
        public Country SelectedCountry
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedCountry;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_SelectedCountry!= value)
                {
                    _SelectedCountry= value;

                    AllCities = get this from your datasource.
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCountry");
                }
            }

        }
```

Hope this will help you..!

Happy learning..!!